# Problem With Redux's Store.dispatch Doesn't Get Updated

Tags: redux, react-redux

Upgrading `meteor` (from 1.4 to 1.7) and `react` (from 15.3.2 to 16.8.6).

```
"react-redux": "^4.4.10"
"redux": "3.5.2"
```

I found my codes were unable to update/store using Store.dispatch(), the Store just not updated.

My ACTIONS file as below:

**actions/config.js**

```
...
export default {
  load({Meteor, Store}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Meteor.call('variables.load', null, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          reject({_error: err.reason });
          return;
        }

console.log("************ Store (A) = "+JSON.stringify(Store.getState()))
        Store.dispatch({
          type: LOAD_CONFIG,
          data
        });

        resolve();
console.log("************ Store (B) = "+JSON.stringify(Store.getState()))
      });
    });
  },
...
```

Both the console.log() were having the following:

```
Store (A) = {"router":{"locationBeforeTransitions":{"pathname":"/settings/config","search":"","hash":"","action":"PUSH","key":"zif4ls","basename":"/crm","query":{}}},"form":{"config":{"syncErrors":{"reportLimit":"Required"}}},"loadingBar":{}}

Store (B) = {"router":{"locationBeforeTransitions":{"pathname":"/settings/config","search":"","hash":"","action":"PUSH","key":"zif4ls","basename":"/crm","query":{}}},"form":{"config":{"syncErrors":{"reportLimit":"Required"}}},"loadingBar":{}}
```

Which I do expect it will have something like `"reportLimit":6` , which was confirmed to have loaded into the `data` variable. Instead, I was getting the following error in browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

Is there anything wrong/breaking changes you could think of? As these codes had been working before the upgrade.

---

EDIT:

I've further narrowed down the problem.  It may seems to be my Routes is not calling the Reducer.

I've since change the code in my Routes to remove the need to use require.ensure .

**routes.jsx** (prior)

```
 {
     path: 'config',
     getComponent(nextState, cb) {
         require.ensure([], (require) => {
           Store.injectReducer('config', require('./reducers').config)
           cb(null, require('./containers/config.js'))
         }, 'config')
     }
 },
```

**routes.jsx** (latest, to get rid of `require.ensure`)

```
 {
      path: 'config',
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
      import('./containers/config.js')
      .then(mod => {Store.injectReducer('config', require('./reducers').config); 
      cb(null, mod);});
      }
 },
```

Then I notice that in the reducer:

**reducer/config.js**

```
// ------------------------------------
// Action Handlers
// ------------------------------------
const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
    [LOAD_CONFIG]: (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      data: action.data
    })
};

// ------------------------------------
// Reducer
// ------------------------------------
const initialState = {
    data: null
};

export default function configReducer(state = initialState, action) {
console.log("************ Reducer")
    const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type];

    return handler ? handler(state, action) : state;
}
```

As per logged, function `configReducer` doesn't seem to have been called elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial-and-error, confirmed the problem is with the routing part, final changes:

**routes.jsx** (final)

```
{
    path: 'config',
    getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        import('./containers/config').then(mod => {
            Store.injectReducer('config', require('./reducers/config').default);
            cb(null, mod.default);
        });
    }
}
```

Key points:
1) This is how the to migrate from `require.ensure` (used by webpack) to without relying on webpack (which was my case as am fully using Meteor Atmosphere to run)
2) `mod` and `require(...).xxx` had changed to `mod.default` and `require(...).default` if `reducer` function is exported as `export default`, otherwise said `reducer` will not be called.

Really took me weeks to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Store.dispatch({
      type: LOAD_CONFIG,
      data: data
 });
```

Comment: what is your load func ? i need the detail of this.

Comment: Load function has no problem, it's calling to server to access for data from MongoDB, which already passing back to the data variable. (have tested via log).

Comment: did you check the data after the promise was created ?
`Meteor.call('variables.load', null, (err, data) => {` 
after this line